# How to install node-gyp in Linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/express$ npm install -g node-gyp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp/-/node-gyp-0.6.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp/-/node-gyp-0.6.3.tgz
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___node-gyp.npm
npm ERR! error installing node-gyp@0.6.3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-gyp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user/express
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/express/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
user@user-VirtualBox:~/express$
```

What I am trying is install Node-gyp on a system. I tried to install on system that have linux 12.04 ubuntu OS.

Do someone know how to set permission for installing node-gyp.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try "sudo npm install -g node-gyp"

Comment: Better to actually log in as root and do it; recent versions of npm will switch to running as "nobody" if run under sudo, and that occasionally causes problems.

Answer (score 35):

`npm install -g` installs a package for all users. Therefore, you need administrator rights to install it. Try

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: This fails in Ubuntu 13.04, since node-gyp expects to find a command named 'node', but in Ubuntu 13.04, it is called 'nodejs'.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege In that case, use `sudo ln -fs nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs` to make nodejs known as `node` as well.

Comment: True. I just wanted to express my frustration with the situation :-)

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04 this problem can be fixed by installing 'node-legacy'.

Answer (score -1):

you need administrator rights to install it

try

```
sudo -i

npm install -g node-gyp
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can Try this

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp --allow-root --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score -2):

I've had luck switching to the root user (`sudo su`, --> password), and then running:

`sudo npm install -g node-gyp`

And then you can press Ctrl+D to return to the normal user (i.e., You).

This might help.

[[EDIT]]:
Node-Gyp doesn't support Python 3:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1337

I have no idea why, since Python 3.0.0 was realeased almost 10 years ago.