# -bash: express: command not found;-bash: ejs: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, express, ejs

After I install node in Linux Virtual Server(CenterOS 6.5), I want to install express and ejs ,I met a strange questrion:-bash: `express: command not found`,-bash: `ejs: command not found`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTvVJ.png)

But in "/usr/local/lib/node_modules",ejs has been installed already.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRMM2.png)

I don't know why . Is the node is not installed correcttly or something else?

Hope someone could help me,I have struggle with it for serveral days.

Answer (score 0):

According to the console `"npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/block-stream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load"`,"Inherits "is the key to resolve this problem.

reference ：[enter link description here][1]

### 1.install ejs,and find an error :

```
[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# sudo npm install -g ejs

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/block-stream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream-ignore requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream-npm requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/glob requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/npmconf requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/tar requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
ejs@2.3.4 /usr/lib/node_modules/ejs

[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# ejs -v
-bash: ejs: command not found
```

### 2.install inherits,and resolve the error

```
[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# npm install -g inherits
?
?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadRequestedDeps ?netwo 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
lifecycle                 ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
/usr/local/lib
忖?inherits@2.0.1 

[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# npm install -g express
?
?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadRequestedDeps ?fetch 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadRequestedDeps ?addTm ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?fetchNamed 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?request    ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?fetch      ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?fetch      ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?addNameRan ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?network    忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?addTmpTarb ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?fetch      忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?afterAdd   ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?afterAdd   ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:vary ?network    忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:negotiator ?netw 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:negotiator ?netw ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:mime-db ?request ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:mime-db ?fetch   忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:ms ?network      忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:unpipe ?request  ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:unpipe ?200      忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:ee-first ?fetch  忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:ipaddr.js ?netwo 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:ipaddr.js ?netwo ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:ipaddr.js ?after ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:statuses ?networ 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:statuses ?200    忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:statuses ?fetch  ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:inherits ?304    忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:media-typer ?net 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:media-typer ?fet 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
postinstall:escape-html ??猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
/usr/local/lib
忖猬 express@4.13.3
  忖猬 accepts@1.2.13
  ?忖猬 mime-types@2.1.8
  ??忖?mime-db@1.20.0
  ?忖?negotiator@0.5.3
  忖?array-flatten@1.1.1
  忖?content-disposition@0.5.0
  忖?content-type@1.0.1
  忖?cookie@0.1.3
  忖?cookie-signature@1.0.6
  忖猬 debug@2.2.0
  ?忖?ms@0.7.1
  忖?depd@1.0.1
  忖?escape-html@1.0.2
  忖?etag@1.7.0
  忖猬 finalhandler@0.4.0
  ?忖?unpipe@1.0.0
  忖?fresh@0.3.0
  忖?merge-descriptors@1.0.0
  忖?methods@1.1.1
  忖猬 on-finished@2.3.0
  ?忖?ee-first@1.1.1
  忖?parseurl@1.3.0
  忖?path-to-regexp@0.1.7
  忖猬 proxy-addr@1.0.10
  ?忖?forwarded@0.1.0
  ?忖?ipaddr.js@1.0.5
  忖?qs@4.0.0
  忖?range-parser@1.0.3
  忖猬 send@0.13.0
  ?忖?destroy@1.0.3
  ?忖猬 http-errors@1.3.1
  ??忖?inherits@2.0.1
  ?忖?mime@1.3.4
  ?忖?statuses@1.2.1
  忖?serve-static@1.10.0
  忖猬 type-is@1.6.10
  ?忖?media-typer@0.3.0
  忖?utils-merge@1.0.0
  忖?vary@1.0.1

[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# express -v
bash: express: command not found

[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# npm install -g express-generator
?
?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadRequestedDeps ?netwo 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:sorted-object ?2 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:sorted-object ?f ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:sorted-object ?n 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:sorted-object ?a ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:graceful-readlink ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:graceful-readlink 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
loadDep:minimist ?reques ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
extract ?gunzTarPerm     ?猗忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
extract:sorted-object ?g 忖⑩忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖忖
/usr/local/bin/express -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
/usr/local/lib
忖猬 express-generator@4.13.1
  忖猬 commander@2.7.1
  ?忖?graceful-readlink@1.0.1
  忖猬 mkdirp@0.5.1
  ?忖?minimist@0.0.8
  忖?sorted-object@1.0.0

[root@iZ94ywyr3sxZ node-v4.2.4-linux-x64]# express --version
4.13.1


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895884/how-to-install-node-gyp-in-linux
```